# Rails attach not working anymore - worked before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, model, attachment, wkhtmltopdf

**Situation**

I have a model `invoice` with an attribute `frozenn` which handles `archiving` in my app. Upon `archiving` a PDF is supposed to get generated and attached (an outbound invoice in my app called `out_invoice` [submodel of `invoice`]) with the following `callback`:

```
  def store_physical_copy_on_freeze!
    unless physical_copy.attached? # without attachment attach current pdf permanently
      pdf_str = Home::OutInvoicesController.render(
        template: "home/out_invoices/pdf",
        layout: 'pdf',
        assigns:  {
          out_invoice: self,
          bank_account: company.mean_of_payment_for_invoices
        }
      )
      pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(pdf_str)
      # attach the currently live generated out invoice forever
      physical_copy.attach(io: StringIO.new(pdf), filename: "#{pdf_name}.pdf")
    end
  end
```

**Problem:**

After the method call is finished the attached PDF is not attached anymore (checked on console since it didn't appear in the frontend which it should).

I used `byebug` to debug that with following result: After the `.attach` call the `physical_copy.attached?` is `true` hence one has to assume it works but it doesnt.

This is not new code but old code which has been working before and I havent changed relevant configuration AFAIK. But of cause this might be the reason.

Comment: What have you changed? That's where I'd start.

Comment: @dbugger Nottingham.

Comment: @dbugger Nothing. I observed it not working anymore on production servers. I can check history in git of this file. But must be something unspecific to the app I hope. Checked Code and Looks good. It is not many LOCs. In debugging all looks good meaning file is attached after the ".attach()" call on console. But attachment is not anymore there right after the above method is finished

Comment: The OS hasn't been updated?  Where are the attachments stored? Has some configuration changed on the servers?

Comment: @dbugger the problem occured on my web servers ran by an external service provider. My local OS which has the same issue had no major udate lately (running Xubuntu). Locally the attachments are stored on my hard drive. On the web servers there is a shared directory between the servers which the service provider has set up. I assume the service provider hasn't updated the servers without telling me. Especially if this had an impact on Rails (they run rails servers professionally). Since the issue occurs locally & on servers I assume some issue with the code above. This was working before!

Comment: If nothing changed -- there is no reason for the code to stop working -- ergo something changed

Comment: Ok. Sounds logical. But do you See issues with the Code above? Accidently could have refactored relevant stuff but very unlikely. I never touch config.

Comment: If you changed something -- source control is your best.

Answer (score 0):

A friend (Rails expert) helped me to solve this. This method call was triggered in an `after_save` callback. It seems the models' callback retriggered the callback chain again or something (not fully understood the problem to be honest). He changed the callback from `after_save` to `before_save` which solved above problem. I would have never guessed also by looking at old code but the solution idea was right. Look at the history of changes. Voted the comment up of @dbugger !